# Locally (normal and $\mathfrak{X}$) groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is there any class $\mathfrak{X}$ of groups which shows that the property of being  a locally (normal and  $\mathfrak{X}$) groups is not idempotent? In other words, say $\mathfrak{D}$ the class of group being locally (normal and  $\mathfrak{X}$) group; a locally (normal and  $\mathfrak{D}$) group is a locally (normal and  $\mathfrak{X}$) group?

**For instance**, if we consider the property of being a finite group, is there any group $G$ in which

- every finite subset lies in a normal and (Locally (normal and finite)) subgroup;
- there is a finite subset which doesn't not lie in any normal finite subgroup?

**Notation**

A group $G$ is said to be a *locally (normal and  $\mathfrak{X}$)-group* iff each finite subset lies in a normal $\mathfrak{X}$-group.

Comment: Doesn't any infinite locally finite simple group (such as the alternating group on an infinite countable set) work? Every finite subset is contained in the whole group, which is normal and locally finite, and there are no nontrivial finite normal subgroups.

Comment: @DerekHolt I miss a "normal" in the example. Now I've edited the question.

Comment: You have a confusing double negative in your second bullet point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n \ge 1$, let $P_n$ be a Sylow 2-subgroup of the symmetric group $S_{2^n}$ acting on $\{1,2,\ldots,,2^n\}$, and let $P$ be the union of the $P_n$.

We can take $P$ to be generated by $(1,2)$, $(1, 3)(2, 4)$,
$(1, 5)(2, 6)(3, 7)(4, 8)$, $(1, 9)(2, 10)(3, 11)(4, 12)(5, 13)(6, 14)(7, 15)(8, 16)$, etc, where the first $n$ of these generate $P_n$.

Any finite subset of $P$ lies in $P_n$ for some $n$, and the normal closure of $P_n$ in $G$ is a direct product of countably many copies of $P_n$, which is locally finite and normal.

But $(1,2)$ is not contained in any finite normal subgroup of $P$. There are no nontrivial finite normal subgroups of $P$.

Comment: As usually, thank you Derek! It's a pleasure to be "part" of a site like this with people like you. :)